# Vue2 composition API array property update not updating

Tags: vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I have this component that accepts an array as a property:

```
import {
  defineComponent,
  getCurrentInstance,
  toRefs,
  watch,
} from "@vue/composition-api";

import { RecommendationAnswer, RecommendationQuestion } from "@models";
import { useCalculateInitialCount } from "./calculate-count";
import { useGetAnsweredQuestions } from "./list-questions";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "StepThree",
  emits: ["onSelect"],
  props: {
    products: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => [],
    },
    questions: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();
    const { products, questions } = toRefs(props);

    watch(
      products,
      (currentProducts: any[]) => {
        if (!currentProducts) return;
        const currentQuestions = <RecommendationQuestion[]>questions.value;
        useCalculateInitialCount(currentProducts, currentQuestions);
      },
      {
        immediate: true,
      }
    );

    const selectAnswer = (answer: RecommendationAnswer) => {
      answer.selected = !answer.selected;
      questions.value.forEach((question: RecommendationQuestion) => {
        question.selected = !!question.answers.find(
          (item: RecommendationAnswer) => item.selected
        );
      });
      const answeredQuestions = useGetAnsweredQuestions(
        <RecommendationQuestion[]>questions.value
      );
      instance.proxy.$emit("onSelect", {
        step: 3,
        questions: answeredQuestions,
      });
    };

    return { selectAnswer };
  },
});
```

The **watch** is triggered whenever the products array changes (which happens outside of this component).
I can see that the **watch** fires and then the function `useCalculateInitialCount` fires, which updates the **count** property on an answer.
This is displayed in the template:

```
<v-col cols="6">
  <base-fade-up class="row" :duration="0.1" tag="div">
    <v-col
      class="text-center"
      cols="12"
      v-for="question in questions.slice(
        0,
        Math.ceil(questions.length / 2)
      )"
      :key="question.id"
    >
      {{ question.title }}
      <v-card
        class="w-100"
        outlined
        @click="selectAnswer(answer)"
        v-for="answer in question.answers"
        :key="answer.id"
      >
        <v-card-text class="text-center">
          {{ answer.title }} ({{ answer.count }})
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </base-fade-up>
</v-col>
```

When the component loads, the watch fires and the counts are displayed correctly:

[image]

But when the products update, even though I see the changes in the console.log:

[image]

The template does not update.
Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a work around for this, by created a computed property instead of watching the products.
The entire code looks like this:

```
import {
  computed,
  defineComponent,
  getCurrentInstance,
  toRefs,
  watch,
} from "@vue/composition-api";

import { RecommendationAnswer, RecommendationQuestion } from "@models";
import { useCalculateInitialCount } from "./calculate-count";
import { useGetAnsweredQuestions } from "./list-questions";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "StepThree",
  emits: ["onSelect"],
  props: {
    products: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => [],
    },
    questions: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();
    const { products, questions } = toRefs(props);

    const questionsWithCount = computed(() => {
      const currentProducts = <any[]>products.value;
      const currentQuestions = [...(<RecommendationQuestion[]>questions.value)];
      if (!currentProducts?.length || !currentQuestions?.length) return;

      useCalculateInitialCount(currentProducts, currentQuestions);
      return currentQuestions;
    });

    const selectAnswer = (answer: RecommendationAnswer) => {
      answer.selected = !answer.selected;
      questions.value.forEach((question: RecommendationQuestion) => {
        question.selected = !!question.answers.find(
          (item: RecommendationAnswer) => item.selected
        );
      });
      const answeredQuestions = useGetAnsweredQuestions(
        <RecommendationQuestion[]>questions.value
      );
      instance.proxy.$emit("onSelect", {
        step: 3,
        questions: answeredQuestions,
      });
    };

    return { questionsWithCount, selectAnswer };
  },
});
```

This fixed the issue, because in the template I use the **questionsWithCount** instead of the **questions**

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your array does not have a new item, so for the watcher is the same array with the same amount of items even if one of them has changed. I'm not sure why you have to watch a property but if you need to watch all the changes in the array you can try to make a copy of the array first and then watch that copied array

Comment: I will give this a go, but I don't understand how watching a copied array will help?